Why does xrandr's --mode throw the error "xrandr: Configure crtc 0 failed"
I am on a RockPro64 running Ubuntu Jammy. ARM architecture. It is not detecting the native resolution of my acer ah101 headset. I set the "non-desktop" attribute to 0 and then I try and make a new mode, but when I attempt to set the mode I get an error. Any ideas?
